# Multi Factor in electric meter

Tags: multiplier

We have an engineering workshop.
In the initial stage our connected load was 60 kW. 2 years back we have removed 50% of machineries and now the load is only 30 kW.

In our electric meter manufacture didn’t mention the MF (multiple Factor) but the distributor had written by pen as “40”. From the beginning to till date the MF is taken as 40 to calculate our consumption.

1. As even now MF is calculated as 40 (even after the load is reduced) whether we will be paying extra charges?
2. In another way if an electric meter without MF mentioned by the manufacturer will lead to a wrong calculation if MF calculated by service distributor is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

From this explanation:

https://www.nbpower.com/en/products-services/business/demand-and-energy/understanding-the-multiplier

the multiplication factor is determined by how your metering is set up, not by your load.

Power meters for industrial sites use transformers to bring the current and voltage measurements down to manageable levels. The multiplication factor represents how much these current and voltage values have been scaled down.

For instance, if your meter's current transformer scales down current readings by a factor of 10 and its voltage transformer scales down voltage readings by a factor of 4, your MF would be 10*4 = 40.